# Website layout is broken, <head> is empty and I can't access wp-admin (wp-login)

Tags: wordpress, head, custom-theme

My site's https://www.beckers-trier.de layout and code is sort of broken. I don't code, but the theme is self-developed and I also don't remember changing anything about the site, except for adding the facebook pixel code in the . The Problem is that a few errors are given, which you can see in the wp-login site of my site. I can't login either, being warned that the cookie settings are closed because of a 'surprising output'

Answer (score 0):

The error itself is quite self-explainatory, the server is trying to send some headers but some output has already started.

The warnings at start of the page are very likely to be generated from the PHP interpreter on your machine, either you have a weird `display_errors` directive in your `php.ini` or the constant `WP_DEBUG` on your `wp-config.php` is set to `true`.

Double check both configuration files and make sure the display of the errors are set to off and `WP_DEBUG` to false.